# Countable rank discrete subgroup?

Tags: number-theory, topological-groups

Is there a discrete rank-$\aleph_0$ free abelian subgroup of the topological group $\langle\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{R},+\rangle$?

For example, denoting by $\mathbb{Z}$ the ring of integers and by $\mathbb{P}$ the set of prime numbers, the *'positive' square roots* of the elements of $(1+8\mathbb{Z})\cap\mathbb{P}$:

$\bullet$ Exist in the $2$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_2$ by Hensel's lemma,

$\bullet$ Exist in the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$,

$\bullet$ Comprise a denumerable set by Dirichlet's theorem,

$\bullet$ Correspond bijectively between $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{R}$ via $\{x^2 - p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\colon p\in (1 + 8\mathbb{Z})\cap\mathbb{P}\}$,

$\bullet$ Are $\mathbb{Z}$-independent in the torsion-free additive group of the compact valuation domain $\mathbb{Z}_2$,

$\bullet$ Are $\mathbb{Z}$-independent in the torsion-free additive group of the locally compact field $\mathbb{R}$.

Enumerate these square roots $\{ b_k\cdot 1_{{\mathbb{Z}}_2}\}_{k\ge 1}$ and $\{ b_k\cdot 1_{\mathbb{R}}\}_{k\ge 1}$, respectively, where $1_{\mathbb{Z}_2}$ denotes the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $1_\mathbb{R}$ denotes the identity of $\mathbb{R}$.

Is the rank-$\aleph_0$ free abelian subgroup $\big(\bigoplus\limits_{k\ge 1} \mathbb{Z}b_k\big)\cdot(1_{{\mathbb{Z}}_2},1_\mathbb{R})$ of $\langle\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{R},+\rangle$ discrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not even a discrete free abelian subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{R}$ of rank $2$.  Indeed, suppose $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent.  For any $n$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there is a nontrivial linear combination of $2^nx$ and $2^ny$ whose $\mathbb{R}$-coordinate is within $\epsilon$ of $0$.  Taking $n$ to be large, this linear combination will also have $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coordinate arbitrarily close to $0$.  So, the subgroup generated by $x$ and $y$ contains nonzero elements in every neighborhood of $0$, so it is not discrete.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: @Eric...can a similar argument work if the 2-adic integers in the question are replaced by the profinite integers (direct product of Z_p over all primes p)?

Comment: Yes, essentially the same argument would work.

Comment: Thank you again. Much appreciated.

Comment: For a quotient D of the profinite integer ring given by the ultraproduct of all the Z_p's relative to a nonprincipal ultrafilter U on the set of primes, one can show that WLOG the uncountable characteristic 0 field F given by the ultraproduct of all the prime fields F_p relative to U is a discrete subfield of the complete valuation domain D, where the valued field K=Frac(D) is the ultraproduct of all the Q_p's relative to U and has residue field F. Then one can get discrete countable rank subgroups of  D x R, though useless as compares to Z_2 x R, which yields the 'solenoid' (Z_2 x R)/Z(1,1).

Comment: A particular nonprincipal ultrafilter U (a la Lenstra) will yield the algebraic closure Qbar of Q such that, continuing the construction above, WLOG one has embeddings Qbar \subset F \subset D \subset K. For C the complex numbers, it is intriguing to me that one gets (K x C)/Qbar(1,1) as a sort-of 2D solenoid, with K complete nonarchimedean, C locally compact archimedean, K isomorphic to C, and Qbar(1,1) discretely embedded as a subfield of K x C.

Comment: @Eric...I forgot to put at-Eric above. I do not know how to typeset in the comments...sorry. You answered my question perfectly, so the follow-up rambling is just my thoughts regarding nontrivial algebrotopological settings where, inside a construct of the form (nonarchimedan) x (archimedean), one can obtain discrete countable rank free abelian subgroups. Thanks again for your insight.

Comment: I forgot to add that a compelling property of the field K above is that, like C, it is 'prime agnostic'. K is an overfield of its discrete characteristic 0 residue field F, which is in turn an overfield of Qbar, with Qbar (and even F) discrete in K, contrasted with the density of Qbar in C. The nonarchimedean and archimedean roles of the quotient of the adele ring (Qhat x R)/Q(1,1) \cong (Zhat x R)/Z(1,1), where Z is dense in Zhat and discrete in R, are reversed in (K x C)/Qbar(1,1), where Qbar is discrete in K and dense in C.